# wanna have a designer for a REPX file - VS13/DevExpress

Tags: visual-studio, printing, label, devexpress

I want to open a repx file with a designer.
(but now, I only see the code behind)
I have installed Visual Studio 2013 and DevExpress.

I just want to add 3 paramters to a printer lable. 
The existing file was made with XtraReport - maybe that helps.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, open or create a blank XtraReport file in design mode in Visual Studio. Then, click on the Tasks tag on the upper-left corner of the report design surface. From the pop-up menu, click on "Open/Import" and select a .repx file.

[image: Accessing the Open/Import menu item]